# Null check operator used on a null value - inside row->column->text

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-text

i am learnig flutter and here i was trying to use TextOverFLow.elipsis in a Design flow following=> listvie.seprated=> item builder=> Row=> container,Column=>text,text and i got 'Null check operator used on a null value',
ps;'it's my first time asking a que. here so pardon me if i wrote something wrong

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import 'news_api_get_res_model.dart';

class NewsHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<NewsApiGetResModel>(
        future: getNewsData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<NewsApiGetResModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.articles!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = snapshot.data!.articles![index];
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 5.w,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      data.urlToImage == null
                          ? Container(
                              height: 30.w,
                              width: 30.w,
                              child: Image(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0f/37/10/0f37109d0cc005766e5f9e625467d884.jpg')),
                            )
                          : Container(
                              height: 30.w,
                              width: 30.w,
                              child: Image(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: NetworkImage('${data.urlToImage}'))),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  "${data.title}",
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  "${data.title}",
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(thickness: 2),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<NewsApiGetResModel> getNewsData() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-10-11&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=6c5a2cd029a44eb186c8640325bd2901'));

  var result = jsonDecode(response.body);

  NewsApiGetResModel newsApiGetResModel = NewsApiGetResModel.fromJson(result);
  log('${newsApiGetResModel.status}');

  return newsApiGetResModel;
}
```

hi ,i am learning flutter and here i was trying to use TextOverFLow.elipsis in a Design flow following=> listvie.seprated=> item builder=> Row=> container,Column=>text,text and i got 'Null check operator used on a null value',
ps;'it's my first time asking a que. here so pardon me if i wrote something wrong

Comment: Add null safety checks to all values you are trying to access like: 
"${data.title  ?? ''}". 
To learn more about null safety, refer 
https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

`data` is getting null. It is safe to check null first then use `!`.

```dart
  return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.articles?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = snapshot.data?.articles?[index];

                if(data == null) return Text("Got null");

                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)